# Why is statistics.mean() so slow?

Tags: python, performance, mean

I compared the performance of the `mean` function of the `statistics` module with the simple `sum(l)/len(l)` method and found the `mean` function to be very slow for some reason. I used `timeit` with the two code snippets below to compare them, does anyone know what causes the massive difference in execution speed? I'm using Python 3.5.

```
from timeit import repeat
print(min(repeat('mean(l)',
                 '''from random import randint; from statistics import mean; \
                 l=[randint(0, 10000) for i in range(10000)]''', repeat=20, number=10)))
```

The code above executes in about 0.043 seconds on my machine.

```
from timeit import repeat
print(min(repeat('sum(l)/len(l)',
                 '''from random import randint; from statistics import mean; \
                 l=[randint(0, 10000) for i in range(10000)]''', repeat=20, number=10)))
```

The code above executes in about 0.000565 seconds on my machine.

Comment: the tl;dr is that `mean` is doing a lot more error handling and work than a trivial `sum(x)/len(x)`.

Comment: Not only slow, but mean too. :(

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Python's `statistics` module is not built for speed, but for precision

In [the specs for this module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/), it appears that

> The built-in sum can lose accuracy when dealing with floats of wildly
>   differing magnitude.  Consequently, the above naive mean fails this
>   "torture test"
>
> `assert mean([1e30, 1, 3, -1e30]) == 1`
>
> returning 0 instead of 1, a purely computational error of 100%.
>
> Using math.fsum inside mean will make it more accurate with float
>   data, but it also has the side-effect of converting any arguments to
>   float even when unnecessary.  E.g. we should expect the mean of a list
>   of Fractions to be a Fraction, not a float.

Conversely, if we take a look at the implementation of `_sum()` in this module, the first lines of the method's docstring [seem to confirm that](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py#l119):

```
def _sum(data, start=0):
    """_sum(data [, start]) -> (type, sum, count)

    Return a high-precision sum of the given numeric data as a fraction,
    together with the type to be converted to and the count of items.

    [...] """
```

So yeah, `statistics` implementation of `sum`, instead of being a simple one-liner call to Python's built-in `sum()` function, takes about 20 lines by itself with a nested `for` loop in its body.

This happens because `statistics._sum` chooses to guarantee the maximum precision for all types of number it could encounter (even if they widely differ from one another), instead of simply emphasizing speed.

Hence, it appears normal that the built-in `sum` proves a hundred times faster. The cost of it being a much lower precision in you happen to call it with exotic numbers.

**Other options**

If you need to prioritize speed in your algorithms, you should have a look at [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) instead, the algorithms of which being implemented in C.

NumPy mean is not as precise as `statistics` by a long shot but it implements (since 2013) a [routine based on pairwise summation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685) which is better than a naive `sum/len` (more info in the link).

However...

```
import numpy as np
import statistics

np_mean = np.mean([1e30, 1, 3, -1e30])
statistics_mean = statistics.mean([1e30, 1, 3, -1e30])

print('NumPy mean: {}'.format(np_mean))
print('Statistics mean: {}'.format(statistics_mean))

> NumPy mean: 0.0
> Statistics mean: 1.0
```

Comment: I did a similar test for the module's stdev function and found it to be about 120 times slower than my own simple implementation. These function really must do a whole lot of extra work just to get that extra precision which I don't need right now anyway. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Pandas, but NumPy is built for speed. I don't think it has a mean routine optimized for numerical stability like `statistics.mean`; it just does the naive sum/len, but in C.

Comment: Sufficiently recent NumPy versions do have [an improved summation routine based on pairwise summation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685), but no option for Kahan summation, let alone anything that goes to the lengths the `statistics` module does for accuracy.

Answer (score 8):

if you do care of speed use numpy/scipy/pandas instead:

```
In [119]: from random import randint; from statistics import mean; import numpy as np;

In [122]: l=[randint(0, 10000) for i in range(10**6)]

In [123]: mean(l)
Out[123]: 5001.992355

In [124]: %timeit mean(l)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.01 s per loop

In [125]: a = np.array(l)

In [126]: np.mean(a)
Out[126]: 5001.9923550000003

In [127]: %timeit np.mean(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.87 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** it will be orders of magnitude faster - in my example it was 700 times faster, but maybe not that precise (as numpy doesn't use Kahan summation algorithm).

Comment: "you will have the same precise result" - no, you'll lose precision. How much you lose and whether you care will depend on what the input looks like and what you're using the results for.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 5):

I asked the same question a while back but once I noticed the `_sum` function called in mean on line [317](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/statistics.py#L317) in the source I understood why:

```
def _sum(data, start=0):
    """_sum(data [, start]) -> (type, sum, count)
    Return a high-precision sum of the given numeric data as a fraction,
    together with the type to be converted to and the count of items.
    If optional argument ``start`` is given, it is added to the total.
    If ``data`` is empty, ``start`` (defaulting to 0) is returned.
    Examples
    --------
    >>> _sum([3, 2.25, 4.5, -0.5, 1.0], 0.75)
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(11, 1), 5)
    Some sources of round-off error will be avoided:
    >>> _sum([1e50, 1, -1e50] * 1000)  # Built-in sum returns zero.
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(1000, 1), 3000)
    Fractions and Decimals are also supported:
    >>> from fractions import Fraction as F
    >>> _sum([F(2, 3), F(7, 5), F(1, 4), F(5, 6)])
    (<class 'fractions.Fraction'>, Fraction(63, 20), 4)
    >>> from decimal import Decimal as D
    >>> data = [D("0.1375"), D("0.2108"), D("0.3061"), D("0.0419")]
    >>> _sum(data)
    (<class 'decimal.Decimal'>, Fraction(6963, 10000), 4)
    Mixed types are currently treated as an error, except that int is
    allowed.
    """
    count = 0
    n, d = _exact_ratio(start)
    partials = {d: n}
    partials_get = partials.get
    T = _coerce(int, type(start))
    for typ, values in groupby(data, type):
        T = _coerce(T, typ)  # or raise TypeError
        for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
            count += 1
            partials[d] = partials_get(d, 0) + n
    if None in partials:
        # The sum will be a NAN or INF. We can ignore all the finite
        # partials, and just look at this special one.
        total = partials[None]
        assert not _isfinite(total)
    else:
        # Sum all the partial sums using builtin sum.
        # FIXME is this faster if we sum them in order of the denominator?
        total = sum(Fraction(n, d) for d, n in sorted(partials.items()))
    return (T, total, count)
```

There is a multitude of operations happening in comparison to just calling the builtin  `sum`, as per the doc strings `mean` calculates a *high-precision sum*.

You can see using mean vs sum can give you different output:

```
In [7]: l = [.1, .12312, 2.112, .12131]

In [8]: sum(l) / len(l)
Out[8]: 0.6141074999999999

In [9]: mean(l)
Out[9]: 0.6141075
```

Answer (score 5):

Both len() and sum() are Python builtin functions (with limited functionality), that are written in C and, more importantly, are optimized to work fast with certain types or objects (list).

You can look at the implementation of builtin functions here:

https://hg.python.org/sandbox/python2.7/file/tip/Python/bltinmodule.c

The statistics.mean() is a high level function written in Python. Take a look here at how it is implemented:

https://hg.python.org/sandbox/python2.7/file/tip/Lib/statistics.py

You can see that later uses internally another function called _sum(), which does a few additional checks compared to the builtin functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a faster mean function, the `statistics` module introduced the [`fmean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean) function in python 3.8. It converts its data to `float` before calculating the mean.

(Implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/statistics.py#L321))

A quick comparison :

```py
import timeit, statistics

def test_basic_mean(): return sum(range(10000)) / 10000
def test_mean(): return statistics.mean(range(10000))
def test_fmean(): return statistics.fmean(range(10000))

print("basic mean:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=test_basic_mean, setup="from __main__ import test_basic_mean", repeat=20, number=10)))
print("statistics.mean:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=test_mean, setup="from __main__ import statistics, test_mean", repeat=20, number=10)))
print("statistics.fmean:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=test_fmean, setup="from __main__ import statistics, test_fmean", repeat=20, number=10)))
```

gives me:

```
basic mean: 0.0013072469737380743
statistics.mean: 0.025932796066626906
statistics.fmean: 0.001833588001318276
```

Answer (score 2):

According to that post: 
[Calculating arithmetic mean (average) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716331/calculating-arithmetic-mean-average-in-python)

It should be "due to a particularly precise implementation of the sum operator in statistics".

The mean function is coded with a inner _sum function that is supposed to be more precise than the normal addition but which is a lot slower (code available here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py).

It's specified in the PEP: 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/
Accuracy is considered more important as speed for that module.

Comment: [Link to `_sum` function in statistics.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/statistics.py#L120)  It definitely favours fractions over all else...