# mean function from statistics package is not precise

Tags: python, statistics

I have a list of which I want to know the mean value.
I found online that the mean() function of the statistics package is designed to be precise
( [Why is statistics.mean() so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533666/why-is-statistics-mean-so-slow))
However, I find it rather inprecise, rounding my means.

example, a list (agent.rr) that of length 100 that contains 5 nonzero inputs: -200, -200, -200, -200 and -240.

if I calcualte:

```
statistics.mean(agent.rr)
```

I get the output

```
-10
```

If i calculate:

```
mean(agent.rr)/len(agent.rr)
```

I get the correct output

```
-10.4
```

Why does statistics.mean() not provide the correct answer?

I tried to make some random examples, like:

```
mylist = [1,2,2]
```

But statistics.mean() does seem to provide the correct answer whenever I just manually try some lists, but whenever I call it on the list agent.rr it always rounds.

Comment: Where does `agent.rr` come from? i.e. what is the actual type of that sequence, and what are the types of each numerical element?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. ``statistics.mean([-200, -200, -200, -200, -240, *[0]*95])`` evaluates to ``-10.4``.

Comment: agent.rr gets filled in a loop. rewards = [] . for j in range(100):
r = eval.env.step(action)
rewards.append(r)
statistics.mean(rewards)
. To be able to see the rewards list I save it : self.rr = rewards

Comment: I am afraid that is not helpful either. What is ``eval``, what is ``eval.env``, what is ``eval.env.step``? As has been asked can you please clarify what is the type of the elements in the list?

Comment: It are all integers. eval.env was an error, that should be eval_env. This is an environment I have build (for Reinforcement Learning). It returns a reward for performing an action when being in a certain state

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve]. As noted above, this is not reproducible with a list of all integers.

Comment: @Rens all relevant/required code and examples should be in the original question, not supplied as comments (or external links).