# How to call numpy.mean() and numpy.std() in one function?

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is to create arrays:

```
[original array, mean value, std value]
```

The current code:

```
pd.DataFrame({'recall': [cv_result['test_recall'], cv_result['test_recall'].mean(), cv_result['test_recall'].std()]})
```

I wish to maybe call the array 3 times and do `.mean()`, `std()` function.

Comment: how so?  Show us please.

Comment: I wonder if you might find this question/answer to be of value:  [Numpy mean AND variance from single function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391149/numpy-mean-and-variance-from-single-function).  One of the answers proposes that `SciPy` can provide you both results in a single pass.

Comment: `get_mean_std = lambda array: [array.mean(), array.std()]` -> call it `get_mean_std(array)`

Comment: Are you taking arithmetic means and std of percent values?  These aren't going to mean what you think they mean.

Comment: @Him i am not sure about std of percent values but the value is between 0 and 1. I do a `cross_validate` and want to get the mean of recall_score (if it high, it's good), also the deviation (if it is low, it's good).

Comment: @kidfrom - if `array == cv_result['test_recall']`, then I don't think your lambda reduces the amount of work over what the OPs code already does.  The way Numpy works, `cv_result['test_recall'].mean()` is a single operation.  Doing just `cv_result['test_recall']` doesn't really do anything at all, so if you think you're saving work by computing the "value" of `cv_result['test_recall']` just once, you're not.  In my understanding, that's not the way Numpy works.

Comment: @CryptoFool my goal is to shorten the amount of code I need to write. Tomorrow I got an exam to make 2 model with 2.5 hours (including EDA, data preprocessing). So it's good enough. Anyway, if numpy have agg function like pandas, I would love to try.

Comment: @kidfrom - Hey, sorry friend.  I had missed that you were responding to your own question.  That's why I thought you were being a bit presumptive about what the asker was asking.  You weren't, of course, as you were the asker.